# does space-time expansion affect on fundamental particle?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, space-expansion

does space-time expansion affect on fundamental particle or point particle?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2110/)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to original version of this question, which was:

> Can we find out about expansion if everything from atoms to universe...expanded?

If atoms were expanding, the properties of matter would be changing and we would notice.  Our bodies would rip apart before atoms would significantly expand.

According to [Phantom Energy and Cosmic Doomsday](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0302506)
, first the Milky Way galaxy would be destroyed, then the solar system would become unbound, next the Earth would explode and only at a much greater level of expansion atoms would expand.

Comment: "If atoms were expanding, the properties of matter would be changing and we would notice." Why? If every piece of matter were expanding, every particle, with equal acceleration, nothing would change - all relations would remain the same.

Comment: For example for a hydrogen atom, the [Bohr radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius) would no longer be the appropriate function of other constants, planck's constant, electron mass, speed of light, elementary charge, and permitivity of free space.

Comment: Not really. Relative values would remain the same. It's like with time dilatation, and length contraction in SR - for the moving frame nothing changes, and local observer wouldn't notice. The difference being here that outside observer also wouldn't notice, because the change would be taking place everywhere at the same time and with equal acceleration.